# Using mozilla-django-oidc and djangorestframework-simplejwt together

Tags: python, django, jwt, openid-connect

I have a website that requires both OIDC and JWT authentication. To achieve this, I thought of using the `mozilla-django-oidc` and `djangorestframework-simplejwt` packages together.

However, they don't seem to work together. For example, having the following code snippet in `settings.py` results in only OIDC access tokens being allowed:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'mozilla_django_oidc.contrib.drf.OIDCAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%b %d %Y',
}
```

while the following code snippet results in only JWT access tokens being allowed:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'mozilla_django_oidc.contrib.drf.OIDCAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%b %d %Y',
}
```

(I use the access token by including `Bearer <token>` in my request headers.)

How can I set up the code to make these two packages work together?